# Transaction Count in a Block

Tags: go-ethereum

To get Transaction count on an Account, we use `eth.getTransactionCount(Address)`.

But How will I get the Transaction count from one Block?

Comment: closing the question as I find out the answer.

Comment: eth.getBlockTransactionCount(BlockNumber)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eth.getBlockTransactionCount(BlockNumber)